# To fetch information from various tables gets 'Array to string conversion' error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Sorry, If I sound so dumb on this but recently started php and Codeigniter.

On my product page I am able to print product's details except users details.

I get 'product id' reference from URL and then try to take reference from 'product id' for 'username' associated with it.

Here is the controller:

```
public function index() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    //fetching item details on item page by this item id
    $data['listings'] = $this->my_listings_model->all_listings_details($id);

    //fetching username of user on item page by this item id
    $username = $this->my_listings_model->get_user_name($id);
    //fetching user details on item page by this username
    $data['user_info'] = $this->my_profile_model->get_all_details($username);
    $this->load->view('item', $data);
    }
```

And Model:

```
// Fetch Product details with the help of item id.
function all_listings_details($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vbc_vacation_item_attri');
    $this->db->where('vbc_item_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query->result();
    return $query_result;
}

// Function to select username with the help of item id.
function get_user_name($id){
    $this->db->select('v_posting_member');
    $this->db->from('vbc_vacation_item_attri');
    $this->db->where('vbc_item_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query->result();
    return $query_result;
}

// Collect *All Details* Of A User..
function get_all_details($username){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vbc_registered_members');
    $this->db->where('v_member_username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

I have spent some good time trying to fix it but no good.

Shows error:

> Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: In your `item.php` view file, on very top put `var_dump($data);exit;` and you'll be able to see structure of `$data` variable. String can be output with echo command, but array can not.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it resolved, thanks all for your efforts to help me..

In model function

```
function get_user_name($id)
```

I just had to replace last line

```
return $query_result;
```

with

```
// To get single value instead of array we have to call first row of results
$row = $query_result[0];
return $row->v_posting_member;
```

And it did the trick.